# Select a valid choice. is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

forms.py

```
LANGUAGE_CHOICE = (
   ('C', 'C'),
   ('cplus', 'C++'),
   ('csharp', 'C#'),
   ('html', 'Html'),
   )
language = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICE, label= "Programming Language you know:",widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

templates/formview.html

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 label_field">
 <label for="{{form.language.id_for_label}}"{{form.language.label}}</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 {% for checkbox in form.language %}
     {{checkbox}}<br>
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
 </div>
```

Validation Error

> Select a valid choice. ['C', 'csharp', 'html'] is not one of the
>   available choices.

Could anyone please help me to solve this validation error of CheckboxSelectMultiple

Comment: seems like you need a `MultipleChoiceField` rather than just a `ChoiceField`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the form field (`forms.ChoiceField`) and the widget you've chosen. The form field expects a single option to be selected and POSTed. If you want to store a list of chosen options, then you should use a different form field type, most likely https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield.